# Flutter : firebase_auth depends on firebase_auth_platform_interface Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase for my project. When I click on PUB GET, I get this error!

"Because firebase_auth >=3.5.0 depends on firebase_auth_platform_interface ^6.4.0 which depends on collection ^1.16.0, firebase_auth >=3.5.0 requires collection ^1.16.0.
And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on collection 1.15.0, firebase_auth >=3.5.0 is incompatible with flutter_test from sdk.
So, because quick_chat depends on both flutter_test from sdk and firebase_auth ^3.5.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because quick_chat depends on both flutter_test from sdk and firebase_auth ^3.5.1, version solving failed.)"

Pubspec.yml file:

```
 dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter

  firebase_auth: ^3.5.1
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.1
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you are running an old Flutter version as flutter_test is part of the SDK? Please share output from: flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is:

- flutter_test depends on collection **1.15.0**
- firebase_auth depends on collection **^1.16.0**

And package manager cannot decide which version to use.

What you can do here:

Option 1: Upgrade flutter_test (I believe it comes with SDK, so you need to upgrade Flutter SDK)

Option 2: Downgrade firebase_auth to the version that depends on collection **1.15.0**

Option 3: Specify dependency_overrides (this will force chose the version of the library, use as last resort):

```
dependency_overrides:
  collection ^1.16.0
```

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues with you.
For me it takes a couple step. You can consider these steps and choose wisely which isnt for you

1. Upgrade my flutter, because I currently have 2.8 and now is 3.x

   *`flutter upgrade`*
2. After that, still has the same error. I do this one on VS Code terminal

   *`flutter pub upgrade`*

   *`flutter pub outdated`*
3. And then I increase the minSDKVersion of my flutter by going to flutterDirectory(NOT PROJECT DIRECTORY) > packages > flutter_tools > gradle > flutter.gradle.
   Edit the `*static int minSdkVersion = 16*` to `*static int minSdkVersion = 19*`

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

try add this one.

```
dependency_overrides:
  collection: ^1.16.0
```

it will give you a warning on your runner window like this. But it will be okay

```
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:
! collection 1.17.0
```